# IndexedDB No Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, indexeddb

I have a plugin written in JavaScript that creates/connects to an IDB, checks the data inside the stores and populates if necessary and then returns data requested. The plugin works fine in Chrome/FF however does not seem to want to work in Safari 7.1.

The problem I am having at present is that when I create the database on an iOS device I do not get a callback to the on success or on error functions and furthermore when I create the database on Safari on Mac I get a blank error back.

Here is a snippet of the code, it is within a function inside a plugin called database. var dbName = string and var dbVersion = 1

```
 database = {
    init: function(callback){
      //TEMP FOR DEBUG  - DELETE DB IF EXISTS
      window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
      //Now create & init
      var req = window.indexedDB.open(dbName,dbVersion);  
      console.debug('DBName/Version',dbName,dbVersion);
      req.onabort = function(event){
        console.error('Aborted!',event.target,req);
      }
      req.onerror = function(event){
        console.error('DB Init',event.target);
      }
      req.onblocked = function(event){
        console.error('Blocked',event);
        alert("Please close other tabs with this website open!");
        return;
      };

      req.onsuccess = function(event){
        //Will be called after upgrade if that is called
        console.info('success called');
        db = req.result;
        console.debug(db);
        dbOpen = true;
        //Check Object Stores Are Correct
        var obs = db.objectStoreNames;
        if((!!(typeof callback == 'function')))
          callback.call();
      };
      req.onupgradeneeded = database.upgrade;
      console.debug('Did something happen?',req);
    },
```

After the open() function I have a console debug that prints the parameters supplied to open & at the end after all the callbacks I have a debug which prints 'Did Something Happen' along with the request.

On Safari for Mac when I run the function it will print this into the console: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrshdjhzazg2ixo/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2018.11.01.png?dl=0

And when run on iOS and having the web inspector on mac open an error is not even produced, just seems to skip everything - output is the same as image above but there is no console error produced.

However, what is most odd is even though an error is produced on Safari on Mac, when I refresh the page there is a database that is showing in the resources pane although no stores within it;
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqg4tbqp1vzffp1/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2018.14.08.png?dl=0

If anyone could share some experience or give a hand I would appreciate this - been trying to crack it for hours now and its driving me around the bend - especially as it works in every other browser!

Many Thanks,
Jayden

Comment: you you using the indexDB websql polyfill?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory.deleteDatabase

After viewing the docs here - I concluded that the deleteDB is most likely being called after it has opened. However either way, I have refactored the code so that the init is run after the on success is now called on delete and this has now rectified the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Why not wait for `onsuccess` callback on `deleteDatabase` method?